# daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, daemon

When I start the Android Studio, the following errors occur. I cannot create virtual device and cannot connect device via USB.

> * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037 adb: CreateProcessW failed: Access is denied. (5)
>   * failed to start daemon error: cannot connect to daemon 'C:\Users\Abdullah\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

I have tried via:

1. adb nodaemon server in command line
2. netstat -ano | findstr "5037" in command line. No list displayed in cmd. No adb in task manager.
3. adb start-server in command line, produce same error as above.
4. trying to start adb manually, no window opened and no error dialogue opened.

I'm using on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC.

Comment: `CreateProcess failed: Access is denied.` For some reason it is failing to start the 'adb' process. Check the file exists / check permissions / try to run it manually from the command line.

Answer (score -2):

I had same problem. My solution:

1. Launch Windows Task Manager and find adb.exe not in the Android Studio group. Kill the task.
2. In terminal Android Studio, execute adb start-server